# isolcpus and latency issue

Tags: linux, performance, x86, perf, tlb

I have config grub isolcpus = 8 in the server kernel 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64.

I have a C++ application called `a.exe`, one of the threads called t1 affinity to core 8, then I observe `perf cycles:u -C 8`, look it works fine to me.

Question 1 :

I observe `[k] apic.timer.interrupt` showed in perf from time to time ,
I know every core has its timer interrupt , in /proc/interrupts , core 8 Local timer interrupts happened 1 time per sec, I like to ask whether 
[k] apic.timer.interrupt showed in perf is the event of /proc/interrupts Local timer interrupts ?!

Question 2 :

`perf dTLB-load-misses,iTLB-load-misses -C 8` shows a lot of dTLB,iTLB misses happened in Core 8.

`a.exe` has 15 threads, only t1 affinity to Core 8 , the other threads (said t2 ~ t15 ) consume a lot of memory(heap especially) , I like to know whether huge virtual memory of a.exe  would effect TLB-misses in Core 8 which only t1 run in it?!

t1 use much less heap and stack data memory than t2...t15 do , all t1 to t15 is in a.exe so they share the same virtual memory address, Is it possible that frequently malloc/free action in t2...15(none of them in core 8) would effect core 8 dTLB misses?!

Comment: Setting affinity for t1 to core8 doesn't stop other threads from being scheduled there.  For that, you should set their affinity to `~8` (i.e. any core except 8).  Does your CPU have hyperthreading?  If so, then other threads could still share the same physical core with your t1.  I think Intel CPUs statically partition most of the dTLB (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/737933), though, so you should be fine there.

Comment: If your kernel has Meltdown mitigation enabled, every system call or interrupt will flush the TLB for that CPU (because it reloads `cr3` with a different page table).  Process-context ID may avoid a full TLB flush, but I have no idea if your 3.10 kernel would use that, or if you have Meltdown mitigation at all.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation

Comment: I do isolcpus and observe cpu core 8 , only t1 of a.exe run in it , no context switch at all  ,  and the other thread(t2 to t15) run at other cores,exactly what I need . and  lscpu showes : Thread(s) per core: 1, so it is hyperthreading disabled .

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176624/how-do-i-check-if-kpti-is-enabled-on-linux  i check my linux , it does not have KPTI enabled.

Comment: *Is it possible that frequently malloc/free action in t2...15(none of them in core 8) would effect core 8 dTLB misses?!* Yes, that's possible.  When the page tables for the whole process change, all cores running the process need to invalidate the relevant TLB entries.  If those `malloc` / `free` are actually resulting in memory being given back to the kernel with `munmap`, then `mmap`ed again, then yeah they probably have to send an inter-processor interrupt to core 8 as well to run `invlpg`.  But it wouldn't have to flush the whole TLB, so IDK.  Are you using hugepages?

Comment: No , in my case there is no hugepage yet .

Comment: @Peter , thanks for your kind informations , What you said invalid tlb Entries is quite new to me , I have a question about this detail , TLB cache in core 8 need to be refreshed just because t2...t15  in other cores do a lot of malloc/free ?!  means while page tables of a.exe rebuilt , kernel would invalid TLB cache of all cores , so , even core8 did not do malloc/free at all , it still suffer TLB misses , just because t1,t2,...t15 share the same virtual memory address ,  share the same page tables ,  Am I correct ?!

Comment: Then align your large allocations by 2M, and use `madvise` for them or set `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag` to `always`.  That should help a lot with TLB misses.

Comment: *just because t2...t15 in other cores do a lot of malloc/free*.  No, only if those malloc/free can't be satisfied from the free-list in user-space, and it results in some `mmap`/`munmap`.  But yes if that happens, after t2 unmaps a page, the kernel can't let a TLB entry on core 8 let t1 read or write it.  `munmap` in one thread affects all threads, because that's what sharing the same address space / page-tables means.

Comment: And no, it shouldn't invalidate the entire TLB on core 8, just the entry that was unmapped.  But possibly it's costing more invalidations.  The [`invlpg` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INVLPG.html) takes a virtual address.  `mmap` / `munmap` in other threads might not explain your core 8 / t1 TLB problem at all, but I'm pretty sure `munmap` will cause the kernel to interrupt t1 and `invlpg`.  (Changing a page from invalid to valid doesn't require TLB invalidation, because x86 guarantees that's not needed.  If the CPU wants to do negative caching, it has to snoop / be coherent.)

Comment: @Peter , thanks , let me digest first , you really help a lot .

Comment: @Peter ,  I have disable transparant_hugepage  in my linux server , so I'd like to google madvise for more details, thanks .

Comment: Depending on how you disabled THP (which sounds like a bad idea), `madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)` might not help.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt says it *is* possible to set it up so the kernel only uses them inside `madvise` regions, but IDK why you'd disable hugepages unless your hardware is really old and has poor hardware TLB support for them.

Comment: thanks , peter , I will take a try for transparant hugepage and observe what happen .